# Javascript Replace Using Regex With A Non-Capturing Group

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to remove the ordinals in a date string.

I need to verify that there is at least one digit before the ordinal, that way we know it is an ordinal and not part of a word. Here is the proper regex:

```
/(?:\d)(st|nd|rd|th)/g
```

Now, when I do a regex replace on a string in Javascript, I end up replacing the leading digit before the ordinal that was "captured" by my non-capturing group as well, which you can see here:

```js
var inpt;

function swapText()
{
  var str = inpt.value;
  var reg = /(?:\d)(st|nd|rd|th)/g;

  str = str.replace(reg, "");
  
  inpt.value = str;
}

function init()
{
  inpt = document.getElementById('str_data');
  var btn = document.getElementById('swap_btn');
  btn.addEventListener('click', swapText, false);
}

setTimeout(init, 0);
```

```css
body {
  font:13.23px "Open Sans", Verdana, sans-serif;
}

input {
  min-height:30px;
  height:auto;
  width:auto;
  padding: 6px 8px;
  color: #424242;
}

.btn {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 8px 12px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 500;
 line-height: 1.428571429;
 text-align: center;
 white-space: nowrap;
 vertical-align: middle;
 cursor: pointer;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 border-radius: 4px;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 -o-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
}

.btn-success {
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #5cb85c;
 border-color: #4cae4c;
}

.btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #337ab7;
    border-color: #2e6da4;
}

input, button, select, textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
}

button, html input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: button;
}

button, select {
  text-transform: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="str_data" value="The 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and 4th" />
<button id="swap_btn" class="btn btn-primary" >
  Swap Text
</button>
```

*Code snippet not working? Check* [**this JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/WebWanderer/e5ycnq3n/).

Now, after poking around the suggested matching questions, I found that in some languages, non-capturing groups are ignored in regex matches. Is this the case for Javascript?

For example, if I have the string `The 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and 4th` and I were to run a `string.match` with the regex I provided above, this would be my output:

```js
var str = "The 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and 4th";
var opt = JSON.stringify(str.match(/(?:\d)(st|nd|rd|th)/g));
document.body.innerHTML = opt;
```

As you can see, my non-capturing group was ignored. Is this why my `string.replace` ignores my capturing group as well? If so, then **how should I replace the "ordinal" in a date string and verify that there is a leading digit (and leave the leading digit of course) in Javascript?** Thanks!

**UPDATE: Here is a snippet with the accepted Regex**

```js
var inpt;

function swapText()
{
  var str = inpt.value;
  var reg = /(\d)(?:st|nd|rd|th)/g;

  str = str.replace(reg, "$1");
  
  inpt.value = str;
}

function init()
{
  inpt = document.getElementById('str_data');
  var btn = document.getElementById('swap_btn');
  btn.addEventListener('click', swapText, false);
}

setTimeout(init, 0);
```

```css
body {
  font:13.23px "Open Sans", Verdana, sans-serif;
}

input {
  min-height:30px;
  height:auto;
  width:auto;
  padding: 6px 8px;
  color: #424242;
}

.btn {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 8px 12px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 500;
 line-height: 1.428571429;
 text-align: center;
 white-space: nowrap;
 vertical-align: middle;
 cursor: pointer;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 border-radius: 4px;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 -o-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
}

.btn-success {
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #5cb85c;
 border-color: #4cae4c;
}

.btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #337ab7;
    border-color: #2e6da4;
}

input, button, select, textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
}

button, html input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: button;
}

button, select {
  text-transform: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="str_data" value="The 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and 4th" />
<button id="swap_btn" class="btn btn-primary" >
  Swap Text
</button>
```

Comment: Do you mean to obtain [this](https://jsfiddle.net/33mfutwg/)?

Comment: JavaScript does not ignore non-capturing groups.

Comment: YES @stribizhev I did! Thats fantastic! Thank you!

Comment: vks posted the same answer.

Comment: I know, it won't let me accept it for 4 minutes. What a fast response team! Thanks again @stribizhev , you've helped me two days in a row!

Comment: Ok, here it is: there is matching with and without capturing in regex. When you capture a part of a pattern (with `()`) this value is saved in a memory buffer. So, capture groups also serve as grouping and subvalue saving constructs. Non-capturing groups (`(?:...)`) only *group* (good for alternatives or optional sequence definition), do not save any subvalues. The rule of thumb for replacing is *match and capture what you need to get and only match what you do not need*.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @stribizhev I really appreciate it.

Comment: Feel free to upvote any of [my JS accepted answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3832970+%5Bjavascript%5D) if you want to thank :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a capturing group and replace by `$1`. Use replace instead of match.

```
(\d)(?:st|nd|rd|th)
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iJ7bT6/6

```
var re = /(\d)(?:st|nd|rd|th)/g; 
var str = 'The 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and 4th';
var subst = '$1'; 
 
var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you pass a regext to `.match()` and the regex has the `g` option (global), the return value from match is an array of all the complete matches; the groups are not returned, just the complete matches. JavaScript isn't ignoring your non-capturing group (nor your capturing group), but because of the `g` flag you just don't get any information back about them.

Answer (score 0):

Variable date replace in url

```
posutochnaja-arenda-nedvizhimost-v-yalte/zhk-morskoy-spusk-v-yalte-id20879?date_from_to=01.12.2021-03.12.2021&clear_cache=Y&_r=3298#rooms-header-block
```

https://regex101.com/r/fgjGuo/1